# Parametric problem: do these 2 comets collide. Am I solving this correctly?

Tags: calculus, parametric

$\text{comet1} = x_1(t), y_1(t)$

$\text{comet2} = x_2(t), y_2(t)$

1. set $x_1(t) = x_2(t)$ and solve for $t$. Since $t$ had a square, I had 2 possible values for $t$ ($t_1$ and $t_2$).
2. substitute $t_1$ into $x_1(t_1)$ and $x_2(t_1)$ to see if values are a match. then substitute $t_2$ into $x_1(t_2)$ and $x_2(t_2)$ to see if thats a match.
3. if it is a match for either time, substitute $t$ value into the $y_1$ and $y_2$. If those match, the comets collide?

What to do if $t$ has a imaginary number? like 7.3 + .12345436756223i?

What do derivatives of comet $x_1'$, $y_1'$ show me? Does this simply show the rate of change of the path the comets have?

Comment: I don't think $t$, if we use it for the **time**, gets an imaginary number.

Comment: Step 2 makes no sense, you _solved_ $x_1(t) = x_2(t)$, to see if the solutions are solutions is just checking your work. If $x1(t) = x_2(t)$ and $y_1(t) = y_2(t)$, the comets coincide at that moment, so they colide. If not, they don't. If $t$ turns out complex, it means the lines just never touch. Just look at the form of $z^2 + z + 1$, its roots are complex and it never touches the line $z = 0$

Comment: Hi, How about when both comets have the same values for x when t = (7.3 + .12345436756223i)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That approach is fine. We can also see when (if ever) their $y$-coordinates coincide first, then check their $x$-coordinates to see if they collided.

If your solutions $t$ to $x_1(t)=x_2(t)$ are imaginary, then the comets never have the same $x$-coordinate at the same time (since we parameterize time with *real* numbers), so the comets certainly don't collide.

$x_1'(t)$ (if defined) is the "horizontal" velocity of the first comet at time $t$. $y_1'(t)$ is likewise the "vertical" velocity of the first comet at time $t$.

Comment: Hi, How about when both comets have the same x when t = (7.3 + .12345436756223i)?

Comment: As I said, we parameterize with real numbers, so that's not a possible meaningful solution.

Comment: Thank you. So is it true to say that if time = a number with an imaginary number, there is no collision?

Comment: If *all* of your solutions have that form, then they do not collide.